# How to get the values of rank inside the foreach loop?

Tags: php, rank

I'm trying to get the rank in each school which is by the way already in asc order. 
for example, I want to print ONLY the rank of schoolToRank[0] outside the foreach loop. 
This is my code on getting the rank in ALL schools by cost, population and topnotchers:

```
    $rankedCost = setter_asc($test);
$rankedPopulation = setter_desc(setter_desc($user_selected_population));
$rankedTopN = setter_desc(setter_desc($user_selected_top));
$echo= ''; 
foreach($rankedCost as $school_toRank => $data){
      echo '(school = '.$school_toRank . ' is rank = ' . $data['rank']. ')';
}
echo "<br>";
foreach($rankedPopulation as $school_toRank => $data){
      echo '(school = '.$school_toRank . ' is rank = ' . $data['rank']. ')';
}
echo "<br>";
foreach($rankedTopN as $school_toRank => $data){
      echo '(school = '.$school_toRank . ' is rank = ' . $data['rank']. ')';
}
```

This is the result of the above code:
[image]

So for example in school 2, rank is 1- How do I access it individually to show only that school with that rank (outside foreach loop)?

Comment: It isn't clear to me what your current output represents, or what output you actually want.  I can suggest that you use a numbered for loop, which would offer the numerical index for each iteration of that loop, instead of using a foreach loop.

Comment: I actually just need to access the school with rank individually. like, school[2] rank=1 outside for each loop.

Comment: Can you please explain what you are exactly trying to do?

Comment: $separater = implode(",", $rankedCost[0]);
  echo $separater;      === in that code it gives the rank of the school in 0 index.. but I get an error "Array to string conversion in..."

Comment: I just want to get the rank of school(through its index like the snip above) outside the foreachloop. Sorry for my english though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an index on the array:

```
$rankedCost[2]['rank']
```

Comment: yeah! saved me! i feel like a retard now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`asort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) method for sorting by rank

Comment: $separater = implode(",", $rankedCost[0]); echo $separater; === in that code it gives the rank of the school in 0 index.. but I get an error "Array to string conversion in....."     === I just want to get the rank of school(through its index like the snip) outside the foreachloop. Sorry for my english though :(

Comment: your comment is not clear can you please post more of the code on what you are doing? And what error you are getting right now